# Why cannot add method in category extension in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, categories

With given class `TestViewController`, if a method is added to its extension. But error will pop up, what is the reason?

Code:

```
@interface TestViewController (){
    -(void) testMethod;
}
```

**Parse error: TestViewController.m:12:5: Type name requires a specifier or qualifier**

How to add a method to extension class which extend a anonymous category? thanks

Comment: Please add more comments about what you've tried and a full sample of the class and the category that you're trying to write

Answer (score 3):

Remove the {}. ivars are declared inside {}, methods are declared outside the {}.

Comment: And add a `@end`